# How to redirect a pased on port and path in apache2?

Tags: apache2

I want to redirect a certain path on my server to another port:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /hello http://localhost:8090/
        ProxyPassReverse /hello http://localhost:8090/
</VirtualHost>

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Aug 22  2017 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
```

When I access `server:80/hello`, I'm presented with a `404`.

I also have:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

What might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know why, I could resolve it replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.